# How to bind a textbox value to a total number of gridview rows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I would like to keep the total current rows of a grid in a label or textbox. The number of rows can be updated by user, database or in the source code meaning it keeps changing periodically.

Is there any way to bind the value of my textbox so that it displays the correct and live total number of rows without having to refresh or re-assign every time?

Comment: You could make a simple class that inherits from DataGridView and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Make your own `MyRowCount` property where the setter calls `NotifyPropertyChanged`, set it when `OnRowsAdded` and `OnRowsRemoved` are raised. Use this class instead of the DataGridView control. So, if you need to add more properties that rise `PropertyChanged` events, the machine is already warmed up.

Comment: What is the `DataGridView` bound to?

Comment: @LucMorin It is connected to a BindingSource and the BindingSource datasource is set to a BindingList.

Comment: Hi @amindomeniko I'm sorry for not getting back to you earlier. If you still want some help with this, I'd be happy to assist. Just to be sure, you want the number of rows or number of items in the BindingList, and NOT the total sum of those items? Also, you want it so that as soon as the number of rows/items changes, no matter the reason for the change, the new number of items is to be displayed in the TextBox?